# Varnish Latest Version Centos 6.1 Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, cache, varnish, apache

Please can someone clarify this for me I'm very confused.

I want to install Varnish for Magento 2.2 Store - Linux CENTOS 6.10 [server] v80.0.22

Im using these instructions to install

For CentOS Users

## yum install -y epel-release

## yum update

## yum install -y varnish

The output I get at the install stage is
Package varnish-2.1.5-6.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Im checking the varnish website and see Latest Varnish version is 6.2.0

Can someone provide instruction to install via CLI SSH putty or provide a link to page with clear instructions - I want to install the latest version

I have checked online all day and found some very different answers but nothing to help me install the latest version or update my varnish to latest

Answer (score 0):

I found this link and followed instructions on magento docs says must be running varnish version 4 or 5 so I upgraded to 5

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish.html

solved